# Calculating a probability that a random number will be between two numbers from a data set

Tags: r, probability

I have generated a random, normally distributed population of data that has a mean of 341.08 and a standard deviation of 3.07. Here's that code:

```
pop <- rnorm(1000, mean=341.08,sd=3.07)
```

I need to find out the probability that a random number picked will fall between 337 and 343 (both numbers included). How would I execute this?

Comment: By "I need to find out the probability that a random number picked will fall between 337 and 343" do you mean, the probability of a normal variable with the given mean and standard deviation, or do you mean the probability of a number chosen randomly from your sample of 1000? If the former, why even mention the sample? A simple use of `pnorm()` suffices to find such theoretical probabilities.

Comment: You can use the cdf of the distribution for this type of theoretical calculation (the answer doesn't actually depend on your sample). You can do `diff(pnorm(c(337, 343), mean=341.08,sd=3.07))`. If you are using your sample, you are not calculating the probability, you are either calculating a frequency or are estimating a probability (but it's not the "true" probability).

Comment: This seems like it may be a stats question instead of a programming question. If you have psuedo-code in mind and can't figure it out please post more info on what you have tried and are doing. If you are asking about statistics, then next time please consider https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, please consider whether you want to know how many items occurred when you generated this particular distribution, or whether you want to know the probability that a generated number will occur between these two if you run the the code many times.

Answer (score 1):

This will tabulate that vector using the bounds you set:

```
table(cut(pop, c(-Inf,337,343,Inf) ))

(-Inf,337]  (337,343] (343, Inf] 
        87        645        268
```

So the fraction of values (which is also the probability) is:

```
table(cut(pop, c(-Inf,337,343,Inf) ))[2]/length(pop)
(337,343] 
    0.645
```

To make this reproducible you would use `set.seed()`.

And to refine the estimate, if this is being asked as a theoretical question, you might either simulate it with `replicate`, or use:

```
pnorm(343, 341.08, 3.07)-pnorm(337, 341.08, 3.07) 
[1] 0.6422225
```

The first method needs only the data. The other two methods would require *knowing* that the data came from a Normal distribution with the specified parameters.